# Is there a way to automatically switch profiles for a RAT mouse?

Tags: mouse

So I bought a Cyborg RAT 7 mouse a while back, and I love it, except for one thing: it's not automatically selecting the profile for the game I've just started.  This is annoying because, for instance, I have the forward and back buttons, as well as the side scroll set up for weapon selection in some games, and if the proper profile isn't selected before starting the game, none of it works.

How can I get my mouse to load the proper profile when I start up a game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [support page](http://cyborggaming.com/support.htm) says

> **Can I link a profile to start when my game starts?**
>   *No. This feature is not part of the R.A.T. software.*

Comment: That's all fine and good, but are there any work-arounds (willing to install Auto-hotkey or Event Ghost to get it to work)?

Comment: Should of gotten a Logitech. . .

Comment: @surasb: I've got Logitech for pretty much everything else.  In fact, the RAT replaced an MX1000 wireless mouse which I had grown rather fond of.  The RAT just seemed to be a league above any of Logitech's gaming mice though.

Answer (score 7):

> **Updater's Notes**: This program is no longer maintained. It does, however have a few versions available on the [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/) project. Links have been updated for the two latest available versions.

**Edit: Updated to 3.1.7! See the changelog below for details**

- CyborgAutoProfiler [Ver. 3.2.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20131012021345/http://cyborgautoprofiler.com/index.html) [Ver. 3.2.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20141014215646/http://cyborgautoprofiler.com/index.html)

I recently bought the Cyborg M.M.O.7 mouse and love the product! But I noticed that they did not include a feature to automatically swap profiles depending on the game or software currently running! It isn't the most required feature but it just makes the operation of the mouse and keyboard much smoother to not have to worry about changing profiles.

- Cyborg Auto-Profiler is a lightweight, yet reliable utility designed to switch profiles for Cyborg input devices.
- When the application detects that a set game or application is running, it will change the profile accordingly. or you can set HotKeys to switch to a specific profile. You can also set a default profile, which is activated when no set processes are detected. For R.A.T Mouse users it can change the DPI mode and Precision Aim Percentages with every individual profile allowing seamless transition and ultimate personalization. M.M.O.7 users can also change the LED colors with specific profiles.

Features Include:

- Supports all Saitek and Cyborg devices.
- Automatic switching of profiles when specific software are detected.
- Default Profile for devices when no set software is running.
- HotKeys for swapping to specific profiles.
- You can choose from 2 types of Software detection.
- Change the DPI mode and Precision Aim settings for each profile for R.A.T devices.
- Change the LED colors of M.M.O.7 device for each profile.
- Launch profiles without ProfilerU Software running.
- Automatic Update option.

Supported Devices:

- Cyborg Mouse R.A.T. 3.
- Cyborg Mouse R.A.T. 5
- Cyborg Mouse M.M.O 7
- Cyborg Mouse R.A.T. 7.
- Cyborg Mouse R.A.T. 9.
- Cyborg Mouse Contagion
- Cyborg Keyboard V.7
- Cyborg Keyboard S.T.R.I.K.E.7
- Cyborg V.5 Rumble Pad for PC/Xbox 360
- Cyborg F.L.Y.5
- Cyborg Command Unit

It has a default feature so when no process is detected it will load it, That is good for a Desktop profile. It can detect a set running process and change the profile accordingly.

R.A.T and M.M.O.7 can change their DPI mode with every individual profile allowing seamless transition.

M.MO.7 users it can change the LEDs with every individual profile allowing seamless transition.

[image: Screenshot]

**Download:**

Download pages at [Ver. 3.2.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20131005192819/http://cyborgautoprofiler.com/download.html) and [Ver. 3.2.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20141015074557/http://cyborgautoprofiler.com/download.html)

Installers available by direct download at [Ver. 3.2.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20131005192819/http://cyborgautoprofiler.com/Downloads/Cyborg%20Auto-Profiler%20Installer.zip) and [Ver. 3.2.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20141015074557/http://cyborgautoprofiler.com/Downloads/Cyborg%20Auto-Profiler%20Installer.zip)

Please let me know any feedback, bugs, or request! Thanks! and I hope I helped make you enjoy your Cyborg products a little more!

---

**Changelog**

> Changes in 3.2.1
>
> - Added: Blue Screen of Death Protection. This setting will inform you in the Profile Settings menu that the profile you have selected may need to have a delay when switching, if selected the profile will not change until no keys have been pressed within the longest macro time in the profile. This will prevent users getting the dreaded BSoD.
>
> Changes in 3.2.0
>
> - Changed: Profile Settings 'Other' Tab has been renamed 'General'
> - Changed: Default Profile setting has been moved to the General tab
> - Changed: Settings Tabs have been rearranged.
> - Fixed: Error reading DPI Mode for some users.
> - Fixed: Active Window mode would change to default profile when viewing ToolTip in Chrome.
> - Fixed: Software now detects when devices are added/removed again.
> - Added: Support for S.T.R.I.K.E.3 Keyboard.
>
> Changes in 3.1.9
>
> - Fixed: Issue where CAP wouldn't close when computer shuts down.
> - Reversed: Minimize button now places the software in the system tray.(Due to a .Net framework bug I had to change it back to this)
> - Changed: Improved softwares ability to read the RAT devices DPI Mode.
> - Changed: Improved error reporting.
>
> Changes in 3.1.8
>
> - Fixed: Active Window: Google Chrome being detected when not the active window.
> - Changed: Improved the Auto-Update feature in general. Now includes MD5 checksum.
> - Changed: Improved Error handling for process detection.
> - Changed: Minimize button now only minimizes the software, the forms X button now places the software in the system tray.
> - Added: Pulse option for M.M.O.7 LED Flow.
> - Added: You can now set the DPI settings for individual profiles.
> - Added: 'Lock Profile Until Process Ends' setting. This will lock profiles from changing until the locked profiles process has ended.

Changes in 3.1.7
- Fixed: Error at software launch/settings.

Changes in 3.1.6
- Added: Support for RATm & MOUS9

- Added: Software now detects when a device has been plugged in or removed.
- Added: New Setting 'Clear Profile' This setting if enabled will clear the profiles on the devices if no process is detected. Default Profile will be disabled if used.
- Added: Software will now re-enable itself when exiting settings or profile settings menu if it was originally enabled.
- Added: Device Information Window in settings.
- Fixed: Issues in detecting some devices.
- Fixed: Start with Windows problem for some users.

Changes in 3.1.5

- Added: VBScript Scripting Support for when profiles are loaded or unloaded. For an example of its use. If you wanted to close 'uTorrent' when you was launching an online game you could use a script to do it with the 'Sub LoadProfile'. If you wanted to open 'uTorrent' after you exited the game just use a script on the 'Sub UnloadProfile'. I will include some sample scripts.
- Added: Preview option in M.M.O.7 LED Flow Settings.
- Added: Custom Color Dialog for LED Settings
- Changed: Improved 'Start with Windows' setting.
- Fixed: Graphics glitch with using enlarge setting with Windows.

Comment: I know I'm gonna give it try when I get home!

Comment: Please be sure to check for updates! I recently reworked the Profile editing to be more user-friendly and cleaned up some stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the [latest drivers](http://cyborggaming.com/download.htm) ?

You might also try the [beta version](http://cyborggaming.com/blog/post/2010/09/06/RAT7-programming-Ie28099m-drawing-a-blanke280a6.aspx) of the programming software.

Comment: Probably not the latest (whatever was on the CD), but @Alpine's answer seems to indicate that wouldn't change anything.

Comment: That's partly why I suggested using beta software.

Comment: Fair, but that page addresses another problem (that I'm not having) and was last updated a year ago.

Comment: The article is old, but the idea still applies. You should badger the developers for a solution and try beta versions as they come out. This mouse cannot succeed on the market without this feature.

Comment: I tried it anyways, and it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Exploring another idea : Does the mouse software has a command-line tool for switching to a named profile ?

Comment: I don't know of one (hence my comment about using auto-hotkey or event ghost).  Unfortunately, I won't be able to answer that tonight either.